# Maximizing the pairwise Frobenuis distance between M othrogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to maximize the pairwise Frobenius distance between $M$ orthogonal matrices. That is, I'm looking for $Q_{i}, i = 1, 2, ... M$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{ 1 \leq i, j \leq M}{\text{min}}
& & || Q_{i} - Q_{j} ||^2_F
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
is maximized. I know there are numerical algorithms that can provide the answer to that. I'm just wondering if the solution has a simple structure. For example, if the solution can be parameterized by a single variable $t$ (and possibly some orthogonal matrix $A$).

Edit: It would also be nice if I someone could lead me to directions on how to bound that.

Comment: In dimensions 3 and higher I expect there will only be nice solutions for very particular values of $M$. Compare to the problem of distributing points on a sphere.

Comment: It's not clear to me where to begin.. Could you please point me to any helpful references?